# "Authorization" header passed in HttpWebRequest getting null when transmitting from hmac client to server

Tags: c#, authorization, httpwebrequest, hmac

We are passing three headers in our `HttpWebRequest`,

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/api/xxx?xid=5");

 private HttpWebRequest SetHeaders(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString();
            request.Headers.Add("ts", timestamp);
            request.Headers.Add("un", cwUserId);

            string representation = String.Join("\n", request.Method, timestamp, cwUserId, request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.ToLower());

            var encryptedKey = Sha1Hash(cwSecretKey);
            string signature = Signature(encryptedKey, representation);

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", signature);
            return request;
        }
```

When this request hits our `api` code:
We try to read headers, we are able to read "ts", "un". But "Authorization" is empty string.

On my api side,
I have `HttpActionContext` actionContext.
When I do:

```
var headers = _actionContext.Request.Headers;
```

The header has:

```
{Accept-Encoding: gzip
ts: 553
un: cwuser
X-REWRITE-URL: /api/usedcarleads/?dealerid=5
}
```

If i change name of header as "Authorizatio", i am able to see header value:

```
{Accept-Encoding: gzip
ts: 858
un: cwuser
Authorizatio: ENsAgXIHql/LJ09D1752SQCIq8Uf8u3xAxLbqr45JG4=
X-REWRITE-URL: /api/usedcarleads/?dealerid=5
}
```

Can someone suggest me why i am not able to pass "Authorization"?

Comment: Did you use wireshark, or enable logging to see if the header is being transmitted ? You can see http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html for instructions.

Comment: It might be that either it is not being transmitted, or on the server, it is not being given to the application. Which case it is will become clearer if you enable logging and get the logfile.